# What is the divergence of a golden spiral using the spiral tool in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I'm using inkscape and am wanting to quickly be able to generate arbitrary golden ratio spirals, but am having trouble figuring out what the divergence would be to create them, I thought it would just be phi, but that didn't work.

Hopefully will be able to find out on my own soon, just checking to see if anyone has the number handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to generate accurate golden ratio spirals with the spiral tool.  Instead I found a way to quickly generate them through parametric curves.

Create a square by pressing CTRL while using the rectangle/square tool.
With the square selected, navigate in the menu to Extensions -> Render -> Parametric Curves ...
Enter these values

```
Start t-value: 0
End t-value: 4.1
Checked -> Multiply t-range by 2*pi
X-value of rectangle's left: -1000
X-value of rectangle's right: 1000
Y-value of rectangle's bottom: -1000
Y-value of rectangle's top: 1000
Samples: 300
X-Function: pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),2*t/pi)*cos(t)
Y-Function: pow(((1+sqrt(5))/2),2*t/pi)*sin(t)
```

I usually have Remove rectangle checked, and Draw Axes unchecked. 
Click Apply.

Credit to ragstian from this Inkscape Forum post: http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=13427&start=25